# How to show $\{u_1,\sum_i^2{u_i},\cdots,\sum_i^n{u_i}\}$ is linearly independent if $\{u_1,{u_2},\cdots,{u_n}\}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, independence

Suppose $\{u_1,{u_2},\cdots,{u_n}\}$ is linearly independent we need to show $\{u_1,\sum_i^2{u_i},\cdots,\sum_i^n{u_i}\}$ is linearly independent. Therefore, suppose

$$
\alpha_1u_1+\alpha_2\sum_i^2{u_i}+\cdots+\alpha_n\sum_i^n{u_i}=0
$$
for some $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\cdots,\alpha_n \in \mathbb{R}$.

We need to show $\alpha_1=\alpha_2=\cdots,\alpha_n=0$.

I know we have to come up with something that uses linearly independence of $\{u_1,{u_2},\cdots,{u_n}\}$ but I don't know how?

Extension: How can we prove the reverse?

Comment: As a hint, expand your sum involving the $\Sigma u_i$ terms and rewrite it in terms of only the $u_i$’s. That is, find the coefficients on the $u_i$’s after expanding. Then use what you know about linear independence.

Comment: You are only required to show that the span of your new vectors are the same as your that of your old vectors since the two sets have the same cardinality (size). Do you see why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose $(\lambda_1,...,\lambda_n)$ is a set of coefficients such that
$$
0 = \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_iv_i \tag{1}
$$
where $v_i = \sum_{k=1}^i u_k$. *We want to show that then one must have $ \lambda_i=0$ for all $1\leq i\leq n$.*

We can rewrite this as
$$
0 = \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i \sum_{k=1}^i u_k= \sum_{k=1}^n \sum_{i=k}^n  \lambda_i  u_k = \sum_{k=1}^n \left(\sum_{i=k}^n  \lambda_i\right)  u_k \tag{2}
$$
and so, by independence of the $u_k$'s, we must have
$$
\sum_{i=k}^n  \lambda_i = 0 \qquad \forall 1\leq k\leq n \tag{3}
$$
Show that this implies $ \lambda_i=0$ for all $1\leq i\leq n$ (e.g., by induction, taking $k$ from $n$ to $1$ in (2)).

---

To prove the converse: assume, again letting $v_i = \sum_{k=i}^n u_i$, that $(v_1,\dots,v_n)$ is linearly independent. Let $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n$ such that
$$
0 = \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i u_i
$$
Noting that $u_i = v_i - v_{i+1}$ (for $1\leq i<n$, we get
$$
0 = \alpha_n v_n + \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \alpha_i v_i - \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \alpha_i v_{i+1}
= \alpha_n v_n + \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \alpha_i v_i - \sum_{i=2}^{n} \alpha_{i-1} v_{i}
= \alpha_1 v_1 + \sum_{i=2}^{n} (\alpha_i - \alpha_{i-1}) v_{i}
$$
By our assumption of linear independence of the $v_i$'s, we have
$0 = \alpha_1 = \alpha_i - \alpha_{i-1}$ (for all $i$). Again by induction, this implies that $\alpha_i = 0$ for all $i$. That shows that $(u_1,\dots,u_n)$ is linearly independent.

Comment: This is confusing

Comment: @Neymar Err... **what** is?

Comment: To the downvoter: please, explain the reason for the downvote? I am willing to improve my answer, but I don't see what the issue currently is.

Comment: I didnt downvote but the way it is written is confusin for the asker probably i mean it is too formal this probably is good answer to someone who already is experienced

Comment: @Neymar I don't see why this is confusing, though. The thing to prove ("if you have a linear combination which is zero, then all coefficients must be zero") is [literally the definition of linear independence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_independence#Definition).

Comment: The way it is writtten is complicated. Too formal and complicated for a beginner . Dont you remember when you was a beginner ?

Comment: @Neymar But it is also **literally** (up to renaming $\alpha_i$ to $\lambda_i$) what the OP *asked* to do. Have you read the question?

Comment: @Neymar Note that the other answers either go a completely different way, or just brush asides the details and just essentially rely on the fact that one can invert triangular matrices with non-zeroes on the diagonal. I fail to see why this is less... "complicated." But sure.

Comment: @lement C.: How can we prove the reverse?

Comment: @Sepide You were also asked to prove the converse? (if $(\sum_{k=i}^n u_i)_{1\leq i\leq n}$ is linearly independent, then so is $(u_i)_{1\leq i\leq n}$) Do something similar, noting that $u_k = \sum_{k=i}^n u_i - \sum_{k=i+1}^n u_i$.

Comment: @Clement C.: Yes.

Comment: @Clement C.: Could you please add it to the answer? I'll revise the question.

Comment: @Sepide Done. You may want to check it carefully, I was in a bit of a hurry.

Comment: @Clement C.: could you please explain the second summation indices change? I understand this is correct but I want to learn how to use it for the future.

Comment: @Sepide which one? In (2)?

Comment: @Clement C.: the first and the second summation, changing the upper and lower bound.

Comment: @Sepide OK, I assume you mean in (2). Think of it as constraints on $(i,k)$: for $$\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{k=1}^i$$we have $1\leq i \leq n$ and, for each $i$, $1\leq k \leq i$: that means the constraint is $$1\leq k \leq i \leq n$$ This can be rewritten as $1\leq k \leq n$ and, for each $k$, $k\leq i \leq n$: that is, $$\sum_{k=1}^n \sum_{i=k}^n$$ Is that clearer?

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to continue: if you write out the terms in the sum you can factor the $u_i's$ to obtain

$$ ( \alpha_1 + \alpha_2 + ... + \alpha_1 ) u_1 + (\alpha_2 + ... + \alpha_n) u_2 + ... + \alpha_n u_n = 0$$

Now use that the u's are LI to obtain a upper triangular system which quite trivially gives $u_i = 0$ for all i by doing back subtitution and the result follows.

Answer (score 1):

A set of vectors $S$ is linearly independent iff the space $\langle{S}\rangle$ it generates has dimension $\#S$. But $V = \langle{v_1, \dots, v_n}\rangle$ and $V' = \langle{v_1, v_1 + v_2, v_1 + v_2 + v_3, \dots\rangle}$ coincide: clearly $V'\subset V$, and 
$$v_i = (v_1 + \cdots + v_i) - (v_1 + \cdots + v_{i-1}).$$

Alternatively, the vectors $v'_i = v_1 + \cdots + v_i$ have $v'_i = gv_i$ for
\begin{align*}
g = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & \cdots & 1  \\ 0 & 1 & \cdots & 1 \\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ 0 & 0 & \cdots & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}
Clearly $g$ is invertible (e.g., $\det g = 1$), so $\dim V' = \dim g(V) = \dim V$.

Answer (score 0):

The matrix that changes one basis to the other set has determinant $1$, since it is upper triangular with all $1$s above and on the diagonal. So you get a basis, since you are applying an invertible matrix to one. For example, when $n=3$, you matrix looks as follows:

$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}.$$